# Splitting an array into more than one array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a dynamic created array:

```
var myArray = ['content_1','content_2','content_3','content_4'];
```

Other times my array could have more items in as such:

```
var myArray = ['content_4','content_4','content_new','content_new','content_new','content_new','content_new'];
```

My if statement looks like:

```
if (myArray.length > 8) { //then do something }
```

If `myArray` has more then 8 items in the array, create a new one, each array can only hold 8 items though. So my first array could have 40 items in, 20 items in, or more... I never know, how could I split these into dynamic arrays, is there a way I can do this?

After the 8th item in `myArray` push those 8 into a new array, then the next 8 (if applicable) and so forth

Comment: You could have a look at the source code of Lodash's `_.chunk` method. https://lodash.com/docs#chunk

Comment: thanks dude! @bendulum been banging my head with this for awhile. I'll definitely check the link out

Comment: or you can write it with a reduce, it's simple enough

Comment: a quick note, your if statement should say `if(myArray.length > 8){/* Do Something */ }`

Comment: @AGE ahh yeah, i'll update now, thanks :)

Comment: @bendulum just wanted to jump on and thank you again! That `_.chunk` method worked brilliant! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You'd either have to store your arrays in another array or create a new variable for each array. Personally I'd use an array to store all the arrays so you can still look through all of them when you need to.

```
var arrays = [['item', 'item'], ['item','item']];

if(arrays[arrays.length].length === 8) {
    arrays.push(['new array']);
}
```

Obviously this won't work for every scenario but it would have to be something similar.